# Bar Charts for Dynamic Number of Series and Dynamic Model Fields

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4.1

We are trying to analyze profits of various companies in various countries using stacked bar charts. Number of countries varies and are obtained from database and plotted on X-axis. 
Number of companies for which profits to be analyzed is also dynamic depending on data available in database.

For Example :

**Store :**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'com.model.MyModel',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            idProperty: 'id',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            successProperty: 'success',
            type: 'ajax',
            url:'profit.action',
            reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                root:'data'
            })
        }     
    });
```

**Model :**

```
Ext.define('com.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
       {name:'countryName',type:'string'},
           {name: 'profit', type:'auto'},
           {name:'companyName',type :'auto'}
     ]
});
```

**Graph Panel :**

```
{
    xtype:'panel',
    width: 1160,
    height: 200,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: 'fit',
            items: {
                xtype: 'chart',
                animate: true,
                shadow: true,
                store: store,
                axes: [{
                    type: 'Numeric',
                    position: 'left',
                    fields: ['profit'],
                    title: 'Profit',
                    grid: true,
                    label: {
                        renderer: function(v) {
                            return String(v);
                        }
                    },
                    roundToDecimal: false
                }, {
                    type: 'Category',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    fields: ['countryName'],
                    title: 'Country'
                }],
                series: [{
                    type: 'bar',
                    axis: 'bottom',
                    gutter: 80,
                    highlight: true,
                    column: true,
                    xField: 'countryName',
                    yField: ['profit'],
                    stacked: true,
                    tips: {
                        trackMouse: true,
                        width: 65,
                        height: 28,
                        renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                            this.setTitle(String(item.value[1]));
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
    }
```

**Generated JSON:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
       "countryName": "Country1", 
       "company1": "100000000",
       "company2": "200000000",
       "company3": "300000000",
             .. .. .. .. .. 
             .. .. .. .. .. 
        },
        {
           "countryName": "Country2", 
       "company1": "400000000",
       "company2": "500000000",
       "company3": "600000000",
             .. .. .. .. .. 
             .. .. .. .. .. 
        },
        {
      "countryName": "Country3", 
       "company1": "400000000",
       "company2": "600000000",
       "company3": "700000000",
             .. .. .. .. .. 
             .. .. .. .. .. 
        }

         .. .. .. .. .. 
             .. .. .. .. .. 
    ],
    "total": 9,
    "success": true
}
```

Number of countries and number of companies is **not fixed**. We are getting the correct data into the store and is reflected in the json, but the graph is rendered with X axis but no bars.

Please help

Thanks